# One site, two domains

Tags: 7, redirection, domain-access

We have a single site that we'd like to have two different domains: `apply.school1.edu` and `apply.school2.edu`.

The site is at `apply.school1.edu` and we'd simply like to create a domain `apply.school2.edu` to point to `apply.school1.edu`. That way we can use the domain to determine what content to load on the page.

How can we do this?

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/multisite/multi-site-sharing-the-same-code-base

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like both sites to use the same code/modules and database (thus sharing users and some content), use the domain access module at https://www.drupal.org/project/domain

If you'd like both sites to have the same code/modules but not the database, check out Multisite at 
https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/multisite/multi-site-sharing-the-same-code-base

Comment: Actually, all I want to do is just add another url to the site.  The rendering would be based on the url.  The changes are very minor and handled through templates.